# Why don't some attributes appear in feature class table when geocoded from a database connection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, database, missing-data

Using ArcGIS 10.8.2, I have geocoded a large table by connecting to the database table through an enterprise geodatabase connection. Several of the attributes only have "1" or "null" as a possibility but after the geocoding, all those fields contain only "null," not recording any of the "1."

If I export a sample of the database table and geocode it from my local disk, no problems--all the attributes carry correctly. Because the database is >250,000 records, I can't export the whole thing to be local.

Comment: There's not much in the way of details for reproducibility here.  Which ArcGIS? Which database? What is the table definition (in SQL)? What are the values for all fields of a row which should have appeared?

Comment: Hi Vince, Arcmap 10.8.2, .sde database. Not sure what you mean by table definition.

Comment: `.sde` is a connection file. The actual RDBMS (and exact version) to which that connection is made is extremely important, as is the table definition (the CREATE TABLE of the table)

Comment: DB2 database. the table is a feature class.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question with the needed details -- "DB2 database" is not at all detailed, nor is "feature class" (all tables with geometry are feature classes, whereas we need to know if specific unsupported column types are used). There also aren't many DB2 users here, so Esri Tech Support is probably a better option.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I worked around the issue by exporting the database table to a geodatabase and geocoding it locally without using the database connection.